# Explanation of missing prototype error message for custom getln function in C

Tags: c, message

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <reg51.h>


void main (void) {
SCON = 0x52;       // serial port configuration
TMOD = 0x20;       
TCON = 0x40;
TH1 = 0xf3;        // 2403 baudrate @12mhz

printf("Hello World");
printf("Please enter some text: ");
scanf(getLine());

}

const char *getLine()
{

    char *line = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch = EOF;

    while (ch) {
        ch = getc(stdin);


        if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
            ch = 0;


        if (size <= index) {
            size += CHUNK;
            tmp = realloc(line, size);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(line);
                line = NULL;
                break;
            }
            line = tmp;
        }


        line[index++] = ch;
    }

    return line;
}
free(str);
```

That's my code. I think I'm calling getln incorrectly. Is there a way to have the function accept input I can pass in from the user?

This compiler is an evaluation version but I believe it contains the libraries I need.

My goal is to accept a "string", or rather an array of chars and then manipulate its order as a skill test. I only have 2000 KB of memory available to write this.

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to pointers and not being able to reference. Help or even just explanations are much appreciated.

I'm using a KEIL compiler.

When I select Program>Rebuilt All Target Files to check my errors I receive the following:

- assembling STARTUP.A51... assembling XBANKING.A51... compiling
  Main.c... MAIN.C(14): warning C206: 'getln': missing
  function-prototype MAIN.C(14): error C214: illegal pointer conversion
  Target not created

Thank you,

Comment: Add `const char *getLine(void);` at the top, below the includes. You need a function prototype to appear in the file *before* the function is used. Otherwise the compiler has no idea what `getLine` is when it hits line 14, and gives an error.

Comment: Your function is supposed to return a const char *, but you are returning a char *, that might be a problem.

Comment: Got it. I changed the function  name at the last minute but i understand

Comment: @Baldrick `const char *getLine()` is *not* a prototype, it's merely a declaration and does not specify argument types. A proper prototype is `const char *getLine(void);`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: You are correct. I've updated my comment, and my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use the real getline function provided by the C library ?

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat `getline` is not a standard C function. It is part of POSIX.1 2008 but apart from this support is spotty. I doubt that a libc for embedded systems provides `getline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly defined the function at the bottom, but the C compiler needs a list of functions, called `prototypes`, at the top. The prototype must include the function type, function name, and any arguments the function takes. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_world(); //This is the function prototype

int main()
{
    hello_world();
}

void hello_world()             //You did this part correctly, but C needs the 
{                             //prototype at the top in order to see this as a 
    printf("Hello, world!\n"); //defined function
}
```

In your case, the prototype would simply be:

```
const char *getLine(void);
```

and then your program would run without any `prototype` errors. 
Cheers!

Comment: Its also important to add the `void` keyword in the prototype if the function accepts no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add:

```
const char *getLine(void);
```

at the top, below the includes.

This is called a *function prototype*, and it needs to appear in your source file *before* the function is used.

You're basically telling the compiler in advance that `getLine` is a function that takes no arguments and returns `const char *`. So even though the compiler hasn't seen the *definition* of the function yet, it can still verify that it's being used correctly when it appears in your `main` function.

Otherwise the compiler has no idea what `getLine` is when it hits line 14, and gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to avoid defining the function prototype, define the `getLine` before `main`, like

```
#include ...

const char * getLine() {
   ...
}

int main() {
    ...
}
```